# how to integrate two flutter apps in single flutter app being separate module?

Tags: android, flutter

"i want to make Uber like app and have driver app and rider app in flutter how can i integrate them in single one flutter as rider/driver button like in uber"

driver app have its own main.dart file and rider also have

Answer (score 1):

Just create two separate login pages, one for driver and one for client, and give distinct route paths to differentiate them.

Comment: Instead of that you can use single login page check if the user type is driver or user then redirect to desired screen@sabaresh sharp